# Visual studio 2013 not loading references when opening a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Ever since I installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate when I open a solution it appears that none of the external references are being loaded, ie the using statement will be shown in red saying that it cannot find the namespace. This will persist until I run a rebuild and then everything will be fine.

I have tried resetting my environment settings to no avail, I would like to avoid reinstalling if at all possible.

On the project I am currently working on this is happening with the System.Windows namespace, with the error 'Cannot resolve symbol 'Windows'.

If it matters I have the following extensions:

- *AnkhSvn
- *AutoHistory
- Behaviors SDK (XAML)
- Microsoft Advertising pubCenter Service
- Microsoft Advertising SDK
- Microsoft Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC 5 Scaffolding
- Microsoft Web Developer Tools
- NuGet Package Manager
- *Productivity Power Tools 2013
- Visual F# 3.1
- Visual Studio Extensions For Windows Library
- Workflow Manager Activities
- *Xamarin Shell
- *Xamarin.Android

Items marked with * are ones I installed myself and am using.

So has anyone seen anything like this or is able to explain what is happening?

Comment: Tried Re-installing visual studio no difference, although it did retain all of my settings, so it obviously left some files in my profile.

Comment: You can get rid of most of the extensions with this tool (if you don't need them): https://totaluninstaller.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, So I have finally found a solution for this. I am not sure which step actually fixed the issue but here is the flow I went through.

- Uninstall Visual Studio and all components
- Delete Visual studio folder in `%appdata%\local\Microsoft`
- Delete Visual studio folder in documents folder
- Reinstall Visual Studio
- Launch visual studio from command line like so: `devenv /resetsettings`